# How to get rid of NameError in Python?

Tags: python

Hi
I just executed the following code :

```
from Tkinter import *

class LabelDemo( Frame ):
   def __init__( self ):
      Frame.__init__( self )   

      self.pack( expand = YES, fill = BOTH )
      self.master.title( "Labels" )

      self.Label3 = Label( self, bitmap = "warning" )
      self.Label3.pack( side = LEFT )

if __name__ == "__main__":
   LabelDemo().mainloop()
```

It gives me NameError: name 'LabelDemo' is not defined.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Your code runs fine on my computer, so I suspect there's something else you're doing wrong.

Comment: Post the complete traceback, it usually tells you on which line is the error in what file and in what code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warning.py", line 3, in <module>
    class LabelDemo(Frame):
  File "warning.py", line 14, in LabelDemo
    LabelDemo().mainloop()
NameError: name 'LabelDemo' is not defined

Comment: not believable that the code above causes your traceback.

Comment: @aix, I suggest next time that you don't edit the question to fix code indentation when it involves python code. The original question had poor indentation, and would have alerted everyone that the problem was probably an indentation one.

Comment: @Josh Smeaton: Your point is a valid one. However, if you look at the source of the original message, you'll see that the OP's indentation is fine: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f697a472-ca60-46c6-bf12-c6986bf97763/view-source

Comment: @aix, it appeared fine, but turns out it wasn't. The lack of formatting would still have hinted the probability of an indentation problem. To be honest - I probably would have done the same thing you did. Apologies if my comment came off harsh - wasn't my intention.

Answer (score 2):

That code worked fine for me also. There must be an indentation error somewhere. Is that the entirety of the file? Have you got tabs mixed with spaces anywhere?

Edit:

This is your traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "warning.py", line 3, in <module> class LabelDemo(Frame): 
    File "warning.py", line 14, in LabelDemo LabelDemo().mainloop() 

    NameError: name 'LabelDemo' is not defined
```

That is saying that the call to `LabelDemo().mainloop()` is happening within the class definition of `LabelDemo(Frame)`. That means that you have got the `if __name__ == "__main__"` indented. Remove the indentation around the `if __name__ ..` line, and it should work fine.

Final Edit:

There was an edit to the question that formatted the code, presumably because the OP didn't know how to do so. But in the edit, the indentation would have been repaired where it was previously broken.

Comment: okay, I have now made the line if __name__ == "__main__": to if __name__ == "__main_":

Comment: @Sahar, indentation means whitespace. Either spaces or tabs. Remove all spaces and tabs before the `if __name__ ..` line, so it is formatted like the code in your question since it was edited. The `if` should be all the way to the left of your text editor, on column number 1.

Comment: @Sahar, update your question with your actual code in order to check what could be wrong

Comment: Thanks Josh, I have removed unwanted indentation and the code now works!!! Here's the working code: from Tkinter import *

class LabelDemo(Frame):
 def __init__( self ):
     Frame.__init__( self )

     self.pack(expand = YES,fill = BOTH)
     self.master.title("Labels")

     self.Label3 = Label( self,bitmap = "warning" )
     self.Label3.pack( side = LEFT )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelDemo().mainloop()
Thanks all

Comment: @Sahar, do you mind clicking the tick to accept this as the correct answer? HTH.